# Rigid Body Constraint doesn't work

Tags: physics, constraints

I want to limit the rotation of a physical object on two axes so that it rotates only on the X axis. However, Rigid Body Constraint has no effect. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi! First you could "fix" your question, because you gave us exact zero information what you tried. Since it seems like you are a Blender beginner, pls provide blend file so we can check it out on our own and we don't have to ask a lot of questions in the comments, thx.

Comment: and second i wanna say it would be good to use "i cannot make the rigid body constraint work" instead of "doesn't work" which sounds to me like you think it is a bug.

Comment: @Chris, .blend  file: https://mega.nz/file/skhTQLjY#2-RaqH7-LFZph7Rq6GK3gQ0S9MB3zVnSLk5Ignnuuis

Comment: thx, i assume, you want exactly that what John proposes? that works in that way i understood your question -> important: you have to delete your rigid body cache before, else you won't see the change

Comment: Rigid Body constraint is supposed to create a hinge between 2 objects that have Rigid Body themselves, is it the case?

Comment: Hello, @R1senDev.. I've had a look at your file, thanks, but this question really needs fixing to make it clear. We need to know which object you want to constrain, and when. Please just kick off with a 'to a 5-year-old' description of the overall _effect_ you want to achieve: what behaviour you are looking for. Otherwise we might wind up investing work in the right answer to the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

You should explain in detail what you want to achieve. For the moment maybe you've mistaken what is *Rigid Body Constraint*, it is supposed to create a hinge between 2 objects that have *Rigid Body* themselves (see below), which doesn't seem to be what you want.

I don't think that you can constraint the rotation axis of a rigid body falling (*Limit Rotation* constraint doesn't seem to constrain an active rigid body either), except with some tricks like for example a double wall (*Rigid Body > Passive*):

[image]

A quick explanation of *Rigid Body Constraint*: Create 3 objects, here the top object is a *Rigid Body* passive with the *Animated* option activated, the bottom object is a *Rigid Body* active. The empty (it could be a mesh object as well) is the object with the *Rigid Body Constraint*, *Type > Hinge*, rotate it 90° on Y so that its local Z axis will be the axis of rotation, choose top object as first object and bottom object as second object (note that you could only use 2 objects, the empty here could have the constraint and you choose it as first object):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any details of exactly what you're trying to do, I'm going to give the simplest possible answer!

Click the <kbd>padlock</kbd> icons against the <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Rotation</kbd> settings on the Transform panel. Your object will now only be allowed to rotate in the <kbd>X</kbd> direction.

[image]

Now you've supplied your file, this is your file with those settings applied:

[image]